# jQuery flot mouseleave does not work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flot, pie-chart

I've modify my **jQuery.flot.js** and **flot.pie.js** a bit, to make a mouseleave effect on my pie canvas.

**at line 585 flot.pie.js**

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
    triggerClickHoverEvent('plothover', e);
}

function onMouseLeave(e) {
    triggerClickHoverEvent('plotleave', e);
}

function onClick(e) {
    triggerClickHoverEvent('plotclick', e);
}
```

**at line 127 flot.pie.js**

```
if (options.series.pie.show && options.grid.hoverable) {
    eventHolder.unbind('mousemove').mousemove(onMouseMove);
    eventHolder.unbind('mouseleave').mouseleave(onMouseLeave);
}
```

in my javascript **mysite.html**

```
$("#graph1").bind("plothover", pieHover);
$("#graph1").bind("plotleave", pieLeave);
$("#graph1").bind("plotclick", pieClick);
```

the functions **mysite.html**

```
function pieHover(event, pos, obj) {
    if (!obj) return;
    var what = obj.series.name;
    $("a[name=" + what + "]").addClass("hover");
    $("#world #" + what + " path", svg.root()).attr("fill", "url(#orange)");
    $("#world #" + what + " path.water", svg.root()).attr("fill", "#92D7E7");
}

function pieLeave(event, pos, obj) {
    if (!obj) return;
    var what = obj.series.name;
    $("a[name=" + what + "]").removeClass("hover");
    $("#world #" + what + " path", svg.root()).attr("fill", "#68CDF2");
    $("#world #" + what + " path.water", svg.root()).attr("fill", "#B9E4EE");
}

function pieClick(event, pos, obj) {
    if (!obj) return;
    percent = parseFloat(obj.series.percent).toFixed(2);
    alert('' + obj.series.label + ': ' + percent + '%');
}
```

My pieLeave function is totally ignored. What is the problem? Thanks for the help.
More information: [flot example](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/pie.html)

Comment: what is a flot? can you pass a link or a demonstration of how it should work ? and you should really work on your indentation

Comment: [example for flot](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/) :)

Comment: and actually the [flot.pie.js workin demo](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/pie.html)

Comment: as of google chrome 10.0 does not support it all I see is a yellow pie chart,however it works on the ff, I would advise if something is so fundamentally wrong on such well known browser, stay away from it :) find a different solution. Otherwise you have the examples on the right. way to many bugs in its core script. nevermind the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, happened. You simply can't use the mouseleave on the plot because the plot is the whole canvas container, the only way to do this if binds everything to mousemove and check the object's na

```
function pieHover(event, pos, obj) 
    {
    if (!obj) { // if no object (move out of the plot, clear everything)
    $("a").removeClass("hover");
    $("#world g path", svg.root()).attr("fill", "#68CDF2");
    $("#world g path.water", svg.root()).attr("fill", "#B9E4EE");
    //      return;
    }
    else { // clear everything, do something.
    what = obj.series.name;
    $("a").removeClass("hover");
    $("#world g path", svg.root()).attr("fill", "#68CDF2");
    $("#world g path.water", svg.root()).attr("fill", "#B9E4EE");
    $("a[name="+what+"]").addClass("hover");
    $("#world #"+what+" path", svg.root()).attr("fill", "url(#orange)"); 
    $("#world #"+what+" path.water", svg.root()).attr("fill", "#92D7E7");
    }
}
```